# I get an error when I try to initiate the front camera (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I get an error when I try to use the following code:

```
   captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

    //var backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    let videoDevices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice

    for device in videoDevices{
        let device = device as AVCaptureDevice
        if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front {
            captureDevice = device
            break
        }
    }


    var error: NSError?
    var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &error)

    if error == nil && captureSession!.canAddInput(input) {
        captureSession!.addInput(input)

        stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        stillImageOutput!.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
        if captureSession!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            captureSession!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
            previewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
            previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

            captureSession!.startRunning()
        }
    }
```

The line: `var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &error)` is giving me the error: **Variable CaptureDevice used before being initialized**. Can someone help me how to fix this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `captureDevice` may be used before being initialized:

```
var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice

for device in videoDevices{
    let device = device as AVCaptureDevice
    if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front {
        captureDevice = device
        break
    }
}
```

If the loop doesn't find a front camera, `captureDevice` will be used before being initialized.  To work around this, declare `captureDevice` as an implicitly unwrapped optional, and initialize it to `nil`:

```
var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice! = nil
```

Comment: I can accept the answer in 8 minutes, as soon as I can I will accept. Thanks for the very quick reply.